# nullptr accessing class method VS static method

Tags: c++

I am not new to C++ but I was very surprised that this works:

```
struct Dummy {
    int foo() {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Dummy* d = nullptr;
    int ret = d->foo();
    //ret = 1

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that `foo` is per-class and not per-instance but is this a <strike>language feature</strike> people actually use ? Is there a benefit not having `foo` as `static` here ?

Comment: You dereference a null pointer, that leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Just don't do it.

Comment: Im satisfied with knowing this is not a language feature but undefined behavior. Thanks. I would rather have a compiler error at this point tho.

Comment: If you make it static then it becomes global to all instances of that type and you loose the ability to reference specific members of the instance.

Comment: The compiler is not required to emit a diagnostic in this situation.  In this simple situation, a static analysis could detect the undefined behavior.  But in even a slightly more complex scenario, it would be impossible to detect at compile time.  If it is any consolation, my executable does `PinkTurtle.cpp:10:18: runtime error: member call on null pointer of type 'Dummy'`

Comment: @Eljay I think I misspoke what I had in mind - I meant a runtime error actually (Im completely fine with this code *compiling*). Because as far as I remember dereferencing a null pointer would always give me a nullptr exception (tried to access memory location 0x000.......) but this time the code ran fine and it kinda shocked me. I have no idea why I did not get an exception this time?

Comment: Dereferencing a nullptr is undefined behavior.  Some platforms may crash with a segmentation violation, some may merrily run with a broken axle and appear to work, some may terminate prematurely (like mine does).  Or a mix of the above.

Comment: You can Validate the pointer manually, `template <typename T> T* V(T* p) { if (p) return p; throw "Oopsies"; }` and change `int ret = d->foo();` to `int ret = V(d)->foo();`